# Capistrano 3 deployment with multiple developers from GitHub using forward agent

Tags: github, ssh, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

I have an existing capistrano 3 deployment script which I run on my local machine (MacBook). I use agent forwarding and connect with my public SSH key. This all works fine, I have my SSH key added to GitHub and deployments works like a treat with no password. So, now I have a new developer that needs to also be able to deploy from his own machine. Firstly I have added his public SSH key to the server and added to known hosts so he has SSH access.

What do I need to do now so that agent forwarding works for him too?

I tried to copy his public key to the SSH keys in my GitHub account, but showed an error saying the key was already added. I don't understand how why I get this error as only my own SSH key has been added. Should I give him access to the GitHub repository and then he adds his SSH key to his own account?

Does the public key named in the deploy script need to be the same as it is named on the server or as it is on his machine?

Thanks for any help with this, I can't find anything online for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I give him access to the GitHub repository and then he adds his SSH key to his own account?

Yes. The preferred way to do this is to give the new developer access to the GitHub project via his account.

You also add his public key to `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server so that he can deploy. At this point, deployment should work for both of you using your own keys.

Comment: Thanks, I have done this. His public key is now on the server and named as  id_rsa_dev The issue now is that if he tries to test the connection to GitHub using ssh -T git@github.com it tries to use my key id_rsa instead of his and then fails with permission denied. So how do I handle this? The capistrano script ssh options uses forward_agent: true using his local key keys: ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: It also has his own repo set in repo_url.

Comment: please do you know what should happen regarding the key used on the server? @will_in_wi

Comment: If I was to use specify keys: ['~/.ssh/id_rsa_other'] in my capistrano script and leave forward_agent: true would that then use ~/.ssh/id_rsa_other on the server when pulling from Git ?

Comment: I would use SSH Agent for the keys. For example, he could run `ssh-agent bash` and then `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_other` and the deploy Capistrano in that context.